# Delete all files and folders recursively but excluding one folder

Tags: linux, rm

I have a folder structure like this:

```
my-root-folder
├── .git
├── README.md
├── index.css
├── index.js
├── index.html
├── assets
│   ├── image
│   │   ├── logo.jpg
│   │   ├── header.jpg
```

i want delete all files and folder into `my-root-folder` but not the `.git` folder (`./my-root-folder/.git`) and his child.

i have tried with this command, but always delete all:

```
shopt -s extglob && rm -rf ./* !(".git")
```

**Side note i'm in a docker image based on alpine.**

Comment: Please checkout this link, you can gain more information.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file

Comment: Please checkout this link, you can gain more information about it:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `find`:

```
find my-root-folder -mindepth 1 -not -path "*/.git*" -delete
```

Roughly translated, this means: `find` inside `my-root-folder` everything `at least one level deep` (so, exclude the folder itself) that does `not` match the predicate `path contains "/.git"` and `delete` it.

Note that the argument `".git"` is actually a regular expression, so be careful when adapting to other situations. `find` is a very powerful and useful tool, so be sure to check out its documentation!

Comment: but it delete the files into ".git" folder? i need to exclude child and the folder itself

Comment: You are right, I am updating the answer to hold the children. =)

Comment: You could replace `*/.git*` with `my-root-folder/.git*` if you need to delete nested `.git` folders that are not directly under `my-root-folder`. Or, if you want it even cleaner, you can `cd` into your folder and use `find . -mindepth 1 -not -path "./.git*" -delete`

Answer (score 1):

This find command delete nested .git as well :

```
find .  -mindepth 1 -path ./.git -prune -o -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
```

`-path ./.git -prune -o` excludes only top level .git

One drawback is you may see messages because `find` tries to access directories it has already deleted.

Remove `echo` once you are happy.

Comment: FYI: This answer assumes you are running from `my-root-folder`. If not, replace the DOT after find and the first DOT in `./.git` with `my-root-folder`